# PowerBI DAX get COUNT DISTINCT with GROUP BY , see SQL query below

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have got this following **SQL query** that gives me the correct value from the database.

```
SELECT
  SUM( DISTINCT_ORDER_NUMBERS )
FROM
(
  SELECT STORE_KEY,
         COUNT( DISTINCT TRANSACTION_NUM ) AS DISTINCT_ORDER_NUMBERS,
         DATE_KEY,
         TRANSACTION_TYPE_KEY
  FROM Pos_Data
  GROUP BY STORE_KEY,
           DATE_KEY,
           TRANSACTION_TYPE_KEY
)
AS A
```

I am however facing challenges writing a DAX formula for a measure in Power BI  Here is what I have tried so far but I get an error.

**Total Number Of Orders**

```
VAR _TotalOrders =
SUMMARIZE('Pos_Data',
    'Pos_Data'[STORE_KEY],
    'Pos_Data'[DATE_KEY],
    'Pos_Data'[TRANSACTION_TYPE_KEY],
    "DISTINCT_ORDER_NUMBERS",
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Pos_Data'[TRANSACTION_NUM]))

RETURN SUM(_TotalOrders[DISTINCT_ORDER_NUMBERS])
```

Please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SUM` function expects a base table rather than a calculated table.

Try this instead:

```
VAR _TotalOrders =
SUMMARIZE('Pos_Data',
    'Pos_Data'[STORE_KEY],
    'Pos_Data'[DATE_KEY],
    'Pos_Data'[TRANSACTION_TYPE_KEY],
    "DISTINCT_ORDER_NUMBERS",
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Pos_Data'[TRANSACTION_NUM]))

RETURN SUMX(_TotalOrders, [DISTINCT_CHECK_SEQ])
```

---

**Edit:** If the difference you mentioned is related to nulls, then try [this](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/marco_russo/archive/2011/03/08/difference-between-distinct-and-values-in-dax.aspx) in place of `DISTINCTCOUNT`.

```
COUNTAX( DISTINCT( 'Pos_Data'[TRANSACTION_NUM] ), 'Pos_Data'[TRANSACTION_NUM] )
```

The `COUNTAX` function (as opposed to `COUNTX`) does not count nulls.

Comment: Thanks Alexis, the formula does is not throwing an error any more however its not giving me the correct result that I get when I run it from the database query. Maybe my DAX formula doesnt translate to the SQL Query above

Comment: This might have to do with the way SQL and DAX treat nulls. Can you give some simple example data where they are different?

Comment: Alexis thanks a lot, The issue was the NULLs. COUNTAX worked like a charm. Much appreciated. You saved me hours of hair pulling and a dozen cups of coffee.